# struct not inheriting virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two structs which inherit from each other, and a parent struct which has no relation to these structs but manages a `std::vector` of pointers for the main class. Here's some code.

Parent class definition:

```
struct Widget {
    virtual void inflate();
}
```

Child class definition:

```
struct Label : public Widget {
    void inflate();
}
```

Function implementations:

```
void Label::inflate(){
    std::cout << "Child function called" << std::endl;
}

void Widget::inflate(){
    std::cout << "Parent function called" << std::endl;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<Widget*> widgets = std::vector<Widget*>();
Label1 = Label();
Label2 = Label();
widgets.push_back(Label1);
widgets.push_back(Label2);
int i = 0;
while(i < widgets.size()){
    widgets[i]->inflate();
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
Parent function called
Parent function called
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you add declaration of label1 and label2?

Comment: Also define Label::inflate with keyword override.

Comment: @setia_ The entire source is available, if you would like. https://github.com/AlgoRythm-Dylan/cursesRant

Comment: Which files I should look into.?

Comment: @setia_ driver.cpp and the header and source files for CursesWidgets and BasicWidgets should include everything

Comment: You have commented Panel ,s inflate function in panel declaration?

Comment: @setia_ I want Panel to inherit the inflation method from the superclass, Widget. Label needs a custom function, however.

Comment: Put all relevant code within the question, as external links can break.  Missing are declarations for `Label1` and `Label2`.  The usage code should be compilable.

Comment: Your usage code can't possibly compile as it is here. You are trying to copy a Label *object* into a Widget *pointer*. Your `push_back` call should look like `wigets.push_back(&Label1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your usage code as the comments already said. I've modified it so that it compiles and runs as expected. I can't tell you the exact problem with your original code though as it doesn't compile.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Widget {
    virtual void inflate();
};

struct Label : public Widget {
    void inflate();
};

void Label::inflate(){
    std::cout << "Child function called" << std::endl;
}

void Widget::inflate(){
    std::cout << "Parent function called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Widget*> widgets = std::vector<Widget*>();
    Label Label1;
    Label Label2;
    widgets.push_back(&Label1);
    widgets.push_back(&Label2);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < widgets.size()){
        widgets[i]->inflate();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Link to see it work: https://ideone.com/ETDClF